# full screen fancybox(iframe)

Tags: jquery-plugins, fancybox

I use fancybox plugin on my website and I want to display an iframe in fullscreen.
I use this `<a href="http://www.google.com">This goes to iframe</a>`, and the problem is that the iframe is not displayed full screen.

Check [this](http://www.outboxvision.com/interior/) and click on details to see what I'm talking about.

Why is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the link is incorrect, here's one that I'm using now and it works.

```
<p><a class="fancy fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com">Link name</a></p>
```

In your case "fancy" might need to be changed to fancybox fancybox.iframe. Haven't quite figured out the full screen. It looks like it needs to be done using javascript.